# match entries and fwrite "done " in another colunn in excel

Tags: excel

Suppose i have 2 files named file1 and file2.

In file1 there are 1000 entries in column A, while in file2 there are 100 entries in columnA.

I want to search 100 entries of file2 from file1. If a match occurs, then I need to `INSERT` done in columnB in file1.

Comment: and the entries are in number

Comment: thank u so much....i got an answer....

Answer (score 0):

In the **file1** worksheet's B2 cell use this formula,

```
=if(isnumber(match(a2, 'file2'!a:a, 0)), "done", "")
```

Fill down.

Comment: and the entries are in number.

Comment: and the entries are in number.

Comment: so formula is same or not ?

Comment: Please review the documentation for the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) and come back with a **specific** question once you have tested the formula and found that it does not do what you want.